# Sun (or Oracle) JDK parser and error recovery technique

Tags: parsing, java, error-recovery

Does anyone know what parsing and error recovery technique used by Sun (or Oracle) JDK parser? I'm interested especially in the high quality error messages produced (exact error location + related statement and/or expression, pretty neat) and the ability to skip as little token as possible before continue parsing (so it can still parse correct construct and doesn't miss the nearest possible errors)